# How can I make the same function work for different arrays?

Tags: arrays, function, three.js

What I want is to execute a function when I want to push the positions of vertices of a 3D geometry to an array. I want to use the same code all over again when I want to push positions to an array. Is it even possible to use a function when I want to push something in an array? Can somebody help me please?

This is my code:

```
function sphereposition() {

    sphere.position.x + sphere.geometry.vertices[i].clone().x * 1;
    sphere.position.y + sphere.geometry.vertices[i].clone().y * 1;
    sphere.position.z +sphere.geometry.vertices[i].clone().z * 1;   

}

for ( var i = 0; i < particles; i++ ) {
    positions.push( sphereposition(); );
}
```

Comment: your function doesn't have any assignments so it is hard to figure out what you want to push. the sphere.positions or the sphere.geometry.vertices?

Comment: Both. On http://jsfiddle.net/g36xmtrj/ you can see how my push to the _positions_ array works.

Comment: ok, so you are pushing triplets of floats. so then your question is not clear. what is the difference between `positions of vertices` and `positions`. all are 3D points. so it is up to you what to do with them (interpretation).

Comment: I wanted to replace all those three lines with one function, because im going to use different arrays and all those different arrays will have the same three lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not a three.js question but more of a programming question `How do I organize my data`?

You have several options (not exhaustive list).

1. Add a position to cone2. Then all your data will be `world space position + vertices position`
2. Use two arrays. One for `object world space position` and one for `vertices position`
3. Premultiply your vertices by the object matrix and store the result.

Using option 1:

```
    function getObjectData (object) {

        var world_position = object.position;
        var vertices_position = object.geometry.vertices;

        for ( var i = 0; i < particles; i++ ) {
            positions.push(
                world_position.x + vertices_position[i].x,
                world_position.y + vertices_position[i].y,
                world_position.z + vertices_position[i].z,
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: More about my question: I'm going to use more then one animated sprites transitions. There will be two transition functions on different positions. I will have transition_1, transition_2 and that's why I'll also need more then one arrays. The arrays will be named positions_1, positions_2, objects_1 and objects_2. What I basically wanted is to copy and paste those three lines when I need them. So I think that the option two will work. I also though that using one function instead of using those three lines will get better perfomrance.